# screenProps.object returns ALWAYS null in navigationOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I want to put a part of data (username) from fetched props on navigation header. Please see my `navigationOptions`.

```
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => ({
    ...
    title: !_.isNil(screenProps.outfitDetail) ? 
    `${screenProps.outfitDetail.user.username}'s Post`: ''
  });
```

My problem is that `title` always return a blank string because `screenProps.outfitDetail` is always null. What am I doing wrong here? Why is it returning null all the time?

I fetched outfitDetail props using Redux on `componentWillMount()`

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    const { token, hType} = this.props;
    this.props.fetchOutfitDetail(token, hType, id);
  }
```

I could get the outfitDetail props from `render() function`.

```
render () {
    const detail = this.props.outfitDetail;
    if(detail) {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.root}>
        ...
```

I call my component by its id

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('OutfitDetail', {id})
```

Doing same thing on User Profile

```
console.log(this.props.currentUser.username); <- prints username
this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {username:this.props.currentUser.username});
```

But in Profile screen, it can't get `screenProps.username` either.

Comment: Where are you passing `screenProps`?  And where are you setting `outfitDetail`?  It's hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for asking. I thought I can just put `screenProps` to get props for the current screen. Should I pass it somewhere?                                            For you second question, I set outfitDetail on mapStateToProps. So I could get the object from render() function.

Comment: This is really hard to debug because I can't pass console.log() on navigationOptions :(

Comment: Are `outfitDetail` and `fetchOutfitDetail` injected by a Redux container ?

Comment: @Freez Yes, they are. I think screenProps is not connected to the screen's props. So I think I have to put props on the Component.

Comment: I just edited the question and as you can see I'm not passing any props. I think it can get not props from redux(mapStateToProps) but the props when the component is called. Very interesting.

Comment: Damn it. I don't think it's right way to do it though. I have to store logged in user's username on props :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access to your screen's component properties with `screenProps`. To use values from Redux store in your `navigationOptions` you can see solutions in this thread :

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/940

**Solution 1:**

```
static navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: <SomeTitle />
};
```

where `SomeTitle` is a Redux connected component.

**Solution 2:**

Pass state as navigation helper to your root navigator

```
<MainNavigator 
  navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ 
    dispatch, 
    state: state.nav, 
    globalState: state 
  })}
/>
```

And use it like this

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  ... 
  title: globalState.path.to.your.data
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer with many details. But I'm rather passing extra props when I call a component. I think your approach works but I'm choosing simple way to do so. :P

Comment: Voted up your answer though. Thanks for your input. Very appreciated it

Comment: I think you can solve this problem (+200 bounty) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-tabnavigator-when-user-logs-out-from-other-screen